# VB.net (duck numbers) ( even numbers )

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, math, numeric

I need to use VB to find **Duck Numbers** and **Even Numbers** as it said in the question.

**Q1**:VB.NET application to check whether a number is a Duck Number
or not

**Q2**: even numbers within a range of two
Example

```
Start Number = 10
End Number = 100
Output:
Even numbers from 10 to 100 are
12 14 16 18 22 24 26 28 …….
```

I'd like to show you guys what i have been doing and please correct me with explanation if possible.

### Program 1:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i, j, k As Integer
    j = 0
    i = TextBox1.Text
    k = i
    While i > 0
        If (i Mod 10 = 0) Then
            j = 1
            Exit While
            i /= 10
            If k > 0 And j = 1 Then
                MsgBox("The Given Number Is a Duck Number.")
            Else
                MsgBox("The Given Number Is not a Duck Number.")
            End If
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

---

### Program 2

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
End Sub



Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim i, j, k As Integer
    i = TextBox1.Text
    j = TextBox2.Text
    Label4.Text = "Even number from " & i & " and " & j & " are "
    For k = i To j
        If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
            Label3.Text = "" & i + 2
        ElseIf i Mod 3 = 0 Then
            Label3.Text = "" & i + 1
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: What on earth is a duck number?  If its just even numbers then why aren't you calling them even numbers?

Comment: Do you realize there is a difference between VB and VBA and VB.NET etc?  You post is tagged incorrectly.

Comment: A Duck number is a number which has zeroes present in it, but there should be no zero present in the beginning of the number. For example 3210, 7056, 8430709 are all duck numbers whereas 08237, 04309 are not....

Comment: I never would have considering leading zero's to change a number...  so the even numbers are unrelated, that's the other problem, correct?  (The title confused me.)

Comment: I have something that may help you (assuming the answer to my question was yes)

Comment: @M.Karami Would you consider numbers `10` and/or `100` as even numbers in the range `10` to `100`?  Asking as your example starts with `12`, implying that `10` isn't included.

Comment: By that definition, `04309` is a duck number, because `04309` is just a string representation of the numeric value `4309`, which is a duck number.

Comment: Also: make sure you have Option Strict turned on. The first code sample shouldn't compile with it on, which means you likely have it turned off, and that's not good practice.

Comment: Finally, the first problem I noticed in the first sample is the `Exit While` will prevent you from ever reaching any of the rest of the code. I think you need to puzzle this out more on your own. Anything we provide isn't going to help you learn until you can understand some of the basics better.

Answer (score 1):

I work with VBA constantly but rarely VB and don't even have a compiler, but I think these solutions should give you an idea of an easier way to do this.

```
Public Function isDuck(n As Long) As Boolean
    If InStr(CStr(n), "0") <> 0 Then isDuck = True
End Function
```

or  even simpler:

```
 Public Function isDuck(n As Long) As Boolean
    isDuck = (n Like "*0*")
End Function
```

---

```
Public Sub listEvens(nStart As Long, nStop As Long)
    If nStart / 2 <> nStart \ 2 Then nStart = nStart + 1
    Do While nStart <= nStop
        Debug.Print nStart
        nStart = nStart + 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

...or another way (just for the same of being tricky!) would be to replace the `If nStart...` line with:

```
nStart = nStart - (nStart / 2 <> nStart \ 2)
```

...or even:

```
nStart = nStart -(nStart \2=1)
```

... and then with a `For..Next` loop:

```
Public Sub listEvens(nStart As Long, nStop As Long)
    For nStart = nStart - (nStart / 2 = 1) To nStop Step 2
        Debug.Print nStart
    Next
End Sub
```

So I can't help directly with the If you have Excel or another MS Office product you can paste these in there to demonstrate, and I suspect they'll be pretty easy for you to "adjust" into VB.

```
listevens 7,16
 8 
 10 
 12 
 14 
 16 
?isduck(1234)
False
?isduck(0123)
False
?isduck(12034)
True
```

Although I did find this from here:

Or perhaps better for you:

```
Dim oddsZeroToFifty() As Integer
oddsZeroToFifty= Enumerable.Range(0, 51).Where(Function(x) x Mod 2 = 1).ToArray
```